# Can't load video into android application

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, ffpyplayer

I have the following code on my desktop with Pillow and ffpyplayer installed. It works fine on Pycharm, however on android it wont start and crashes.

My buildozer requirements:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,plyer,android, jnius, kivmob,Pillow,ffpyplayer,libshine,libx264,ffpyplayer_codecs
```

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = Builder.load_string("""
Video:
    source: "Menuscreen.mp4"
    state: "play"
    options: {'eos': 'loop'}
 """)

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

When I run this code I get this error message:

```
File "ffpyplayer/player/player.pyx", line 409, in ffpyplayer.player.player.MediaPlayer.__cinit__

04-18 17:37:03.364 27614 28055 I python  :  TypeError: expected bytes, NoneType found
```

Comment: Are you including the `Menuscreen.mp4` in your apk?

Comment: It is in the same directory as main.py. Just like I have it in pycharm

Comment: But did you use your spec file to make sure it gets included in the apk? Video files are not included by default.

Comment: Good point. No I didn't. I forgot about that completely :/